# Dynamically add method in before(:all)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im testing a Module that can be included in a Controller.
Right now the code looks like that:

```
class GithubAuthorizationController < ApplicationController
  include Frontend::Concerns::GithubAuthorization

  def index
    render inline: "lorem_ipsum"
  end
end

describe GithubAuthorizationController do
  before(:all) do
    @page_content = "lorem_ipsum"
  end
  ...........
```

As you can see I basically create a Test-Controller before the tests are run. Now I would like to add the module and index method in the `before(:all)`-block. I tried:

```
class GithubAuthorizationController < ApplicationController
end

describe GithubAuthorizationController do
  before(:all) do
    @page_content = "lorem_ipsum"

    class < @controller
      include Frontend::Concerns::GithubAuthorization

      def index
        render inline: "lorem_ipsum"
      end
    end
  end
  ...........
```

As I can see in debugger in the `before(:all)` block the `@controller` is defined as `<GithubAuthorizationController ...`. So It is a instance. There Is also no error when running the code, but the tests fails, because of `The action 'index' could not be found ...`

**What do I wrong? How can I move the code to the `before(:all)` block? Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this in rspec is with a controller block:

```
describe GithubAuthorizationController, type: :controller do
  context "with module" do
    controller do
      include Frontend::Concerns::GithubAuthorization

      def index
        render inline: "lorem_ipsum"
      end
    end

    # within this block the controller will be the anonymous controller class created above 
  end
end
```

If you have set `infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers` to false (this is not the default) then you need to do `controller(GithubAuthorizationController)` or you'll inherit directly from `ApplicationController`

Your issue could be down to a missing route - the `controller` helper creates some routes for you (for the default index, show etc.) actions. You can add extra ones in an example with

```
 it "does something with a custom route" do 
  routes.draw { get "custom" => "github_authorization#custom" } 
  get :custom
    ...
end
```

Comment: Hi, great answer. I would really like to use this solution. But right now Im getting ` method_missing': undefined method `controller' for Class`.Do you have an idea why it fails? Can you send me the docs for `controller do`. I was not able to find them. Thanks

Comment: Ok seems to work with `control_class`. Great. Now Im getting the error with `missing routes`. Where would you add the `routes.draw { get "custom" => "github_authorization#custom" } ` block? in the context?

Comment: You may need type: :controller on the spec, as I have just added. See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller#draw-custom-routes-for-defined-controllers

Comment: Thanks! Great Answer!